# PHP - Authenticate with TWO session variables

Tags: php, authentication, session

I am trying to verify a client's membership level. I check two session variables; client username, and their level of membership.

What I want to happen:

- If the user's membership level does not match a level of 3, then they get booted back to the login page.

What actually happens:

- When I login as the user, who does not match the membership level of 3, they still see the content.

(Both variables are set when the user logs in, and I have verified that both session variables are strings.)

This is what I have currently:

```
<?php 
  session_start(); 
    if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['level'] == "3") {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You have an incorrect membership level";
    header('location: ../auth/client_login.php');
  }
?>
```

Am I missing something simple, or is this the wrong way to go about checking two session variables? Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: Check $_SESSION['username'] value or print whole print_r($_SESSION). It would be easy to debug what is actually going wrong.

Comment: *"Authenticate with TWO session variables"* - About that; you do realize that `if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])` checks if it is *not* set, right? Yet, wanting to check at the same time if this equals "3" `$_SESSION['level'] == "3"`. Those 2 conditions seem to contradict themselves.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner si right your checking on one end if the username is not set  and then your checking if the level is 3   should you wanna test both conditions separately i suggest running an or condition   or replacing  !isset to just isset

Comment: @ShubhamAzad - thank you for your suggestion - that was helpful

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - that was it - some incorrect logic on my part - thank you for pointing that out

Comment: @nick_halden You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else stumbles upon this post, I spotted the error that @FunkFortyNiner posted above in my initial question. I fixed it by implementing a trivial fix:

`if((isset ($_SESSION['username'])) && ($_SESSION['level']!=3)`